# How to extract aac audio from an mp4 file to m4a

Tags: ffmpeg, avconv, mp4, aac

How can I extract the aac audio from an mp4 file?

I tried with ffmpeg and `-acodec copy` but if i use mp4 as output it will still encode the video and I get the same file size.

If I use m4a as output it will somehow still encode the video and I get almost the same filesize.

With aac as output I can't open the file in puddletag although the file size suggests the video was stripped

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I finally found the solution myself in using mp4 or m4a as output format and adding -vn to prevent also copying the video.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vn -c:a copy output.m4a
```

(Source: https://superuser.com/a/706622/180675)

Seems simple now :]

Fast and lossless stripping

Comment: At least on November, 2022, the command that actually works is `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vn -c:a aac output.m4a` i.e. the **copy** parameter must be replaced by **aac**.

Comment: @YuriSucupira the command in the answer worked perfectly well for me (Jan 2024, ubuntu 22.04)

Comment: @RobAudenaerde Maybe it's because I'm currently (2024-02-09) using XUbuntu 24.04 (development/testing/unstable build). Even though this is a cutting-edge version (since its stable release is going to happen only 2 months from the date of this post), I believe it's important that I report here what worked for me because it seems that those who migrate to version 24.04 on April 2024 are going to experience the same issues that I did (and, therefore, are going to have to use the same command that I used).

Answer (score 5):

Another option:

```
MP4Box -add infile.mp4#audio outfile.m4a
```

MP4Box is part of the gpac package.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, you can also do it by using vlc.  The script below strips all *.mp4 files in the current directory to *.m4a.  There are some error messages which can be ignored.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

quote=\"  
executable="/usr/bin/vlc"
argument3=vlc://quit

#parameters
accessvalue=file
muxvalue=mp4

for x in *.mp4; do
    inputname="${x}"
    strippedname=${x%.mp4}
    outputname=${strippedname}.m4a
    quote_outputname=${quote}./${outputname}${quote}
    echo ${inputname}
    echo ${quote_outputname}
    qtranscode=#transcode{vcodec=none}: # rm this commnt, cont' nxt line !!
    standard{access=$accessvalue,mux=$muxvalue,dst=${quote_outputname}}
    argument1="$inputname"
    argument2=--sout=$qtranscode
    "$executable" -I dummy "$argument1" "$argument2" "$argument3"
done
```